# Filtering specific type from list

Tags: java

How to get all dogs only?

In C#, you can use `animals.OfType<Dog>()`, is there any shortcut in Java?

```
private static void snoopDogs() {

    Animal[] animals = { new Dog("Greyhound"), new Cat("Lion"), new Dog("Japanese Spitz") };

    for(Dog x : animals) { 
        System.out.println("Come over here");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Class%29) and the JDK collections,

```
Iterable<Dog> dogs = Iterables.filter(animals, Dog.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, just need to use `Arrays.asList` so it can be Iterable. Iterables doesn't look as shortcut as C#'s OfType though, but is passable as one-liner anyway :-) `for(Dog d : Iterables.filter(Arrays.asList(animals), Dog.class)) {`

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to do this, but you can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
private static void snoopDogs() {

    Animal[] animals = { new Dog("Greyhound"), new Cat("Lion"), new Dog("Japanese Spitz") };

    for(Animal a : animals) { 
        if( a instanceof Dog ) {
            System.out.println("Come over here");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its supported out of the box. However, it is very easy to add with only a few lines of code:

```
   <T> List<T> ofType(List<? extends T> collection, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
        List<T> l = new LinkedList<T>(); 
        for (T t : collection) {
            Class<?> c = t.getClass(); 
            if (c.equals(clazz)) {
                l.add(t);
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
```

For example:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SubListByType {
    class Animal {
        String breed;

        Animal(String breed) {
            this.breed = breed;
        }

        String getBreed() {
            return breed;
        }
    }

    class Dog extends Animal {
        Dog(String breed) {
            super(breed);
        }
    }

    class Cat extends Animal {
        Cat(String breed) {
            super(breed);
        }
    }

    <T>  List<T> ofType(List<? extends T> collection, Class<? extends T> clazz) {
        List<T> l = new LinkedList<T>(); 
        for (T t : collection) {
            Class<?> c = t.getClass(); 
            if (c.equals(clazz)) {
                l.add(t);
            }
        }
        return l;
    }

    void snoopDogs() {
        Animal[] animals = { new Dog("Greyhound"), new Cat("Lion"), new Dog("Japanese Spitz") };

        for(Animal x : animals) {
            System.out.println(x.getClass().getCanonicalName() + '\t' + x.getBreed());
        }

        System.out.println();

        // LOOK HERE
        for (Animal x : ofType(Arrays.asList(animals), Dog.class)) {
            System.out.println(x.getClass().getCanonicalName() + '\t' + x.getBreed());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubListByType s = new SubListByType(); 
        s.snoopDogs();
    }
}
```